# How can I redirect terminal output that "refreshes" using '\r'?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am attempting to write a (Bash) shell script that wraps around a third-party python script and captures all output (errors and stdout) into a log file, and also restarts the script with a new batch of data each time it completes successfully. I'm doing this on a standard Linux distribution, but hopefully this solution can be platform-independent.

So here's a simplified version of the shell script, omitting everything except the logging:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/me/script.py &>> /home/me/logfile
```

The problem is the third-party python script's output is mostly on a single line, which is being refreshed periodically (~every 90 seconds) by use of a carriage return ("\r"). Here's an example of the type of output I mean:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time

tracker = 1

print("This line is captured in the logfile because it ends with a newline")

while tracker < 5:
    print(" This output isn't captured in the log file. Tracker = " + str(tracker),end="\r")
    tracker += 1
    time.sleep(1)

print("This line does get captured. Script is done.         ")
```

How can I write a simple shell script to capture the output each time it is refreshed, or at least to periodically capture the current output as it would appear on the screen if I were running the script in the terminal?

Obviously I could try to modify the python script to change its output behavior, but the actual script I'm using is very complex and I think beyond my abilities to do that easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program should have disabled this behavior when output is not a tty.

The output is already captured completely, it's just that you see all the updates at once when you `cat` the file. Open it in a text editor and see for yourself.

To make the file easier to work with, you can just replace the carriage returns with line feeds:

```
/home/me/script.py | tr '\r' '\n'
```

If the process normally produces output right away, but not with this command, you can disable Python's output buffering.

Comment: Ah, so it looks like I was incorrect when I guessed that the python script was using carriage returns to refresh the line.  Your answer works for the example I gave, so I accepted it, and now I will have to troubleshoot how to capture the output from the actual script I'm using, which must be using some more advanced method to refresh the line. Thanks!

Comment: Ansi escapes probably. That's a harder problem. You can `tr -d '\033'` to delete the escapes that start them and see how messy it is. Maybe your program only uses a few types like color and clearing the screen so that you can replace them with sed. Also, double check that your tool doesn't have a batch mode or non-ansi mode like standard Unix tools do.